# Chrome Extension Get Iframe HTML

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I'm looking for a way to access the HTML or live code of the current page including the HTML inside Iframes in a Chrome Extension. Ideally I'd like to access the DOM and then output a string.

I have researched a lot on the topic and can't seem to find a working solution. I tried `all_frames` with no success. I also tried getting the contents directly which resulted in a cross origin error.

I am new to extensions and not sure how to create this. Since chrome can display the live code natively, I don't see why a plugin can't have this access as well.

**manifest.json**

```
{
"name": "Iframe Source Test",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "Get HTML from Iframe",

"content_scripts": [
    {
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["getPagesSource.js"],
    "all_frames":true
    }
  ],

"browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "icon.png",
  "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>"]
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style=''>
<head>
<script src='popup.js'></script>
</head>
<body style="width:400px;">
<div id='message'>Injecting Script....</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender) {
if (request.action == "getSource") {
  message.innerText = request.source;
}
});

function onWindowLoad() {

var message = document.querySelector('#message');

chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
  file: "getPagesSource.js"
}, function() {
  if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
    message.innerText = 'There was an error injecting script : \n' + chrome.runtime.lastError.message;
  }
});

}

window.onload = onWindowLoad;
```

**getPagesSource.js**

```
function DOMtoString(document_root) {
  var frame = document_root.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
  console.dir(frame);

  var frameContents = frame.contentDocument;
  console.log(frameContents);

  return frame;
}

chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
  action: "getSource",
  source: DOMtoString(document)
});
```

Checking the log, the frame can be accessed. Accessing the contents results in:

Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "null". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

Comment: Aha! There's no need for `"content_script"` section in manifest as it's not connected to `executeScript`. Instead use [`allFrames: true` parameter of executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript). See the linked duplicate post for an implementation example without messaging.

Comment: Thanks guys! I think I can figure it out with this information.Will close question.